# how can i find out that a user is joined to a telegram channel?

Tags: php, bots, telegram

i want when a user is joined to my channel , receive a 
    notification or a text message from my bot .how can i do that?i cannot find 
    something in telegram API. best wishes... .

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** get notification when user joined your channel, but you can use [getChatMembersCount](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmemberscount) to know **someone** joined.